# Does anyone know the part number of this 900MHz LNA/PA front end IC?

Tags: identification, components, power-amplifier, lna, 802.15.4

Please see attached image. This IC is found on a 900MHz 802.15.4 wireless module, presumably working as LNA+PA, QFN16(?,not sure upon further inspection) package, with the following markings:

7 130
23 02
DGSO (might be D650 as suggested by Joshua Markee in comment)

This IC is most likely equivalent to TI's CC1190, or Skyworks' RFX1010. But I don't find IC in TI/Skyworks's offering that has this kind of markings.

If anyone knows, please advise, thanks.

[image: LNA-PA frontend IC for wireless communication]

Comment: It appears that the "DGSO" may actually be "D650" on the markings. Depending on when this was manufactured the 23 02 are possibly week# and year markings. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: ...or possibly DG50.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is [NXP BGA7130](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BGA7130.pdf), an RF power amp. I can't find anything about package marking in the datasheet, but you could ask NXP support to verify.